# HtmlBox (jquery Plugin) not working in ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, razor

I am using .net framework 4.0 with MVC.

I have included HTMLBox (jquery plugin) in my page as I need a WYSWYG editor for my Text area control.

I have a partial view called Instruction where I declare the Textarea control as:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Instruction, new {@cols = 80, @rows = 10 })
```

On a Ajax call I populate this Partial view on my page. Like this:

```
 function EditInstruction(progId) 
    {
            var getUserUrl = '@Url.Action("")';
            var courseType =  $('input:radio[name=CourseType]:checked').val();
            var acadYr = $("#AcadYear").val();
            var sem = $("#Sem").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("EditInstruction", "CustomizeInstructionsAndCheckList")',
                data: { progId: progId, acadYr: acadYr, sem: sem, courseType: courseType },
                cache: false,
                type: "get",
                // callback handler that will be called on success
                success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

               $("#PartailLoadForCheckList").html($(response));  
               callAjaxCallsForCascade(getUserUrl.toString());
               TextEditorForDisplay();


                },
                // callback handler that will be called on error
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                },
                // callback handler that will be called on completion
                // which means, either on success or error
                complete: function () {

                }
            });
        }

 This is the code for TextEditorForDisplay(), where I initialize my HtmlBox

 function TextEditorForDisplay() {

        mybox = $("#Instruction").htmlbox({
       toolbars:[
        [
        // Cut, Copy, Paste
        "separator","cut","copy","paste",
        // Undo, Redo
        "separator","undo","redo",
        // Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough, Sup, Sub
        "separator","bold","italic","underline","strike","sup","sub",
        // Left, Right, Center, Justify
        "separator","justify","left","center","right",
        // Ordered List, Unordered List, Indent, Outdent
        "separator","ol","ul","indent","outdent",
        // Hyperlink, Remove Hyperlink, Image
        "separator","link","unlink","image"     
        ],
        [// Show code
        "separator","code",
        // Formats, Font size, Font family, Font color, Font, Background
        "separator","formats","fontsize","fontfamily",
        "separator","fontcolor","highlight",
        ]
        ],
        icons: 'default',
        skin: 'blue',
        success: function () { alert("Successfully posted"); },
        error: function () { alert("Error posting"); }
        });



    }
The problem I face is that, the HtmlBox works only when it is Loaded first and does not work for the subsequent ajax calls.
```

This is the error I get: `TypeError: d.iframe.contentWindow is null`

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: This is the error I get, 
TypeError: d.iframe.contentWindow is nul1

Answer (score 0):

[**TinyMCE.MVC**](http://nuget.org/packages/TinyMCE.MVC)

MVC Partial Editor Templates For TinyMCE HTML Text Editor

> **PM> Install-Package TinyMCE.MVC**

```
[UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
public string Instruction { get; set; }
```